# Were there corridors inside the curtain wall of medieval castles?

Tags: castles

I've seen this in movies or cartoons sometimes, that they are waling around inside the curtain wall, but hollowing out the curtain wall with a hallway seems like it would lover the structural integrity of the stone structure, that is supposed to withstand poundings from catapults and trebuchets.
I noticed this in the excellent book Stephen Biesty's Cross-Sections Castle, where you can see it illustrated by the author, this is where I first relized the potential structural problem with this. You can see one example from this image below.

[image]
I've looked around on the internet but haven't been able to find any other image sources, like photographs of real castles, that confirms that corridors in the curtain wall was used. Does anyone have any insight into this? Perhaps someone who has actually been to some real castles, unlike me(!)

Comment: You'll see some if you visit a European country with medieval castles. Google "Chemin de rondes" for images. Many are just covered walk ways at the top of the wall, but there are also some where the walk way is into the wall. Barbe Bleu's castle in Tiffauge, Vendée is an example if memory serves.

Comment: There's no standard castle design. They varied considerably depending on who built them, what they were built for and when they were built. So the answer may be yes or no depending on where you look.

Comment: Doesn't a curtain wall get its name precisely because it is more of a separator than a structural fortification? The walls that we designed to get hit by siege weapons are *not* curtain walls pretty much by definition.

Comment: It’s worth visiting castles - you can get a real idea of how solid they were constructed and, if like my cousin, you forget to duck then you can find out how strong a stone archway is - it was only two feet thick... made a solid sound when his head hit it...Learnt quite a few australian words at that point!

Comment: The structural integrity of a wall will be compromised to a degree by the inclusion of a passage (also known as an intramural passage) but by how much depends on how thick the wall is. Dunyvaig Castle on the island of Islay is one example I can think of. One thing to remember is that from the outside the wall looks solid and strong so wouldn't attract any special attention from attackers without specific knowledge. @PhillS Curtain walls are defensive walls that specifically span the gap between two towers (as opposed to a continuous wall with no towers), so are structural fortifications.

Comment: @MrAndySweet: Thanks for your input, however I tried looking for pictures of Dunyvaig Castle, but it is not much more then a pile of rock that's left of this castle. Do you have any pictures showing corridors in the walls of this castle, or how do you know? Have you been there and seen it yourself? I would love to see these corridors in order to get a better understanding of the construction work.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Thanks for teaching me 'Chemin de rondes', I've never heard of that before :) However that refers to the passage way on top of the walls, and that's different. I'm interested in passages INSIDE the wall, since that would effect the durability of the wall itself.

Comment: @KillingTime yes I understand that all castles were different, however what I'm looking for is images of castles that does have corridors in the curtain wall, so if you know of any - please let me know! :)

Comment: @KristofferHelander: Per my comment, the definition includes both. In Barbe Bleu's castle, for instance, there's a [chemin de ronde around midway into the wall](http://www.photo-vendee.com/image/2150-chateau-de-tiffauges-img-0798).

Comment: @KristofferHelander I didn't manage to find a photo, just a reference to the intramural passage here: https://canmore.org.uk/site/38002/islay-dunyvaig-castle